# Request.Browser.Platform not returning iPad, OSX, or Windows7

Tags: asp.net, browser-detection

I'm working on some advanced browser detection, and I've downloaded the [MDBF](http://mdbf.codeplex.com/) browser file from CodePlex.

Unfortunately my Request.Browser.Platform, along with a few other things is returning "Unknown" on both my iPad Mac OSX (Snow Leopard) and on Windows7

Does anyone know of a good advanced .browser file out there that does the same thing for non mobile devices as the MDBF does for mobile devices?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've solved my particular issue (detecting iPad) with the following file in my application's `App_Browsers` folder:

```
<browsers>
  <!-- Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 4_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8C134 Safari/6533.18.5 -->
  <gateway id="IPad" parentID="Safari">
    <identification>
      <userAgent match="iPad" />
    </identification>

    <capabilities>
      <capability name="mobileDeviceModel"               value="IPad" />
      <capability name="mobileDeviceManufacturer"        value="Apple" />
      <capability name="isMobileDevice"                  value="true" />
    </capabilities>
  </gateway>
</browsers>
```

Then in the code I test:

```
if (Request.Browser.MobileDeviceModel == "IPad")
  ...
```

Comment: I prefer: if(Request.Browser.MobileDeviceManufacturer != "Apple")

Answer (score 1):

Use `Request.UserAgent` instead.

[Beware](http://www.jeffdepascale.com/index.php/general/why-the-ipads-user-agent-string-presents-a-problem/) that it includes the word `Mobile` as well:

```
  Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us)
  AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 
  Mobile/7B367 Safari/531.21.10
```

From Apple on preparing content for iPad:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2010/tn2262/_index.html

Comment: This is all great, but I really like using the `.browser` files. Is there a browser file being maintained for this sort of thing? I'd pay to support a good project rather than maintain my own, or hack the info out of the UserAgent.  As new devices are released, this problem will only creep up again and again.