# ASP.NET Browser definition files

Tags: asp.net, browser-detection

Can anyone recommend a good library of .browser definition files that is regularly updated? I've found both OceanSpiders from http://owenbrady.net/browsercaps/ and some definition files from http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41420 but I'm not sure if either are regularly updated (the iPad isnt included for example).

Thanks in advance
Al

Answer (score 3):

These definition files are "regularly" updated by Microsoft, and pushed through Windows Update. "Regularly" might mean years, though.

A hotfix for the browser definition files for IE and Firefox was released recently, see http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx

For better detection of mobile units, like the iPad, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985584/request-browser-platform-not-returning-ipad-osx-or-windows7).