# Do Microsoft regularly update the Browser Definition files?

Tags: asp.net, .net, mobile, browser, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been getting up to speed with MVC4 and custom display modes. All looks excellent, however, assuming I'm right in thinking the `Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice` is based upon `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\Browsers` - does anybody know if Microsoft regularly update these (ie each time there is an update for .NET 4.0 from Windows Update) ?

At a high level, Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice is very useful. Alternatives are (other than custom display modes) such things as WURFL - but can be much more resource-intensive, and WURFL certainly add's about 2.5 seconds to the app startup time.

If anybody has any idea of the answer to this, or whether there is any sort of project which has custom / regularly updated browser definitions, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821741/asp-net-browser-definition-files

Comment: Ok thanks - I did have a good search for a similar question but must have missed that. Will see if anybody has an update.

Answer (score 0):

You really should consider responsive webpage design instead.

Relying on MS to update definition files is ludicrous with so many new devices appearing on the market each year. We made this mistake a number of years ago an quickly realized it is unmaintainable.

Have a look at twitter boostrap instead:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

It's such a fantastic framework for UI and really worth exploring.

Once you get into the responsive design way of thinking you never go back - really is the future of  web UI.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. However, catering for different devices isn't just about the front end layout. It's about optimising EVERYTHING, including what the server provides to the client. Solutions like bootstrap can't do this.

Comment: You shouldn't need to provide different content from the server. That's the whole point of responsive design.

Comment: I'm sorry @geo1701 but that's just not right. For example, what if, on my "desktop version" I want a really fancy slideshow that was very resource-intensive and needed 1/2 a MB of Javascript to run. But on my mobile version I didn't even want to include the script files. "Responsive design" can't deal with that. I've had sort of scenario many times. It's not just about "layout".

Comment: People still use desktops?

Comment: Yeah, and laptops. Funny that.