# Different OS Version

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have been trying to get version of OS using C#, I get version of Window using **Request.UserAgent** but what about system such as **Linux version**, or **OS X** version, I am able to get the OS Name but not version. And even considering Windows version its pretty much like hard coded like

```
if (Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("Windows NT 6.3") > 0)
{
    osName = "Window 8.1";
}
else if (Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("Windows NT 6.2") > 0)
{
    osName = "Window 8";
}
```

This can be solution for now but not for the other versio I guess. My intended solution could be on the server side or client side.

Thank for you help in advance

Comment: try this tool: https://github.com/tobie/ua-parser

Comment: Also please try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985584/request-browser-platform-not-returning-ipad-osx-or-windows7

Comment: You don't say why you need this information but remember that user agent string can be "faked" and therefore isn't necessarily accurate.

Comment: Thank all, @PaulHunt can you suggest me any link how user agent string can be faked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to get exact version of Client OS because user can change the request header object.

But you can try any ua-parser libraries

Check this nuget package may help you lot 
UAParser 1.0.1

http://www.nuget.org/packages/UAParser/